# Bootstrap and sample mean

Tags: r, statistics, statistics-bootstrap

I have a sample from an exponential distribution, let's say `x<-rexp(30,0.2)`.

I resample this 5000 times with replacement and compute the sample mean:

`resample<-replicate(5000,mean(sample(x,30,replace=TRUE)))`

I do the following histogram to see the distribution of T(X*)-T(X):
`hist(resample-mean(x),freq=FALSE)`

I know that since I have a sequence of iid Exponentials, the sum of this sequence has a Gamma distribution (scaled by the number of Exponential rv's I'm considering (i.e., 30)).

How can I overlay this Gamma distribution to the previous histogram?
I'm trying to use the following `res.range<-seq(min(resample),max(resample),.001)
lines(res.range, dgamma(res.range,shape=1,rate=0.2/30))`
but it seems it doesn't work.

Comment: it works, probably you have a problem of scales. hard to plot mountain and ants in the same plot.

Comment: That's the problem. I'm also trying with various values but the two plots remain with different scales.